# Does it make sense to run OS kernel-level computations on a GPU?

Tags: parallel-processing, operating-system, gpu

I noticed a GPU can have hundreds of cores so that a parallel computation can be largely sped up with them. It seems that in an OS kernel, no parallel algorithms are used for acceleration.

People do parallel computing in users-pace with OpenMP, but why not in kernel-space? I guess there are lots of tasks inside the OS that require parallel processing, like processing multiple network connections and packets, doing cryptography operations, managing memory, searching?... Some firewalls filter and monitor network flows by matching patterns, research-oriented OSes may also analyze the program before running it, which is time-consuming and might be parallelisable.

So why OSes do not use GPUs to improve their performance and throughput? Does it make sense to run OS computations on GPU?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

GPU parallel processing applications require you to run the *exact same operation* hundreds of times. Moreover, you are limited in what operations you can do - branches are generally not an option, nor are traversing pointer chains.

Most kernel operations don't fit into this model; much of what the kernel is doing is managing resources via pointers, including locking. This does not fit into the GPU model at all. As for the other operations you cite:

- Cryptography: GPUs are great for trying to *crack* cryptographic ciphers, but that's not the kernel's job. It usually runs a crypto operation *once*. In this case, the CPU is much faster, since it only needs to do it once.
- Processing network traffic: Packets arrive at different times, and need to be processed with low latency. The GPU *may* be able to do stateless firewall processing, but you'd need to batch up packets and have it work on a few hundred at a time for there to be a benefit - this hurts latency and jitter, and so the job is left to the CPU. Moreover, stateful tracking requires shared, locked access to connection tracking tables, something a GPU is not capable of.
- Managing memory: This is a pointer-heavy operation with lots of locking, and is thus not something a GPU is even remotely well suited for. Moreover, latency is critical, and sending a job to a GPU implies lots of latency.
- Searching: Modern OS kernels don't search. That's a job for userspace - and again, it's a very pointer heavy job.

GPUs are well suited for mathematical kernels where throughput is paramount and latency is a minor issue - numerical simulations, that sort of thing. They are, in general, not well suited for data management, or where latency is critical - which is exactly the kind of stuff OS kernels do. This is why OSes typically don't make use of GPU acceleration.

There are other types of hardware acceleration that OS kernels can and do make use of - some machines have special cryptographic hardware cores specifically designed for doing one-off crypto computations quickly. These can be put to good use by the kernel, as they are better suited to the specific problems the kernel faces.

Comment: Thanks, I agree the latency is the weakness of GPU computing. The PacketShader software claims a hundreds of microseconds latency, not sure if that is still very slow?

The cryptography, I don't know if file severs use encrypted fs/disk or not, GPU may help this kind of cases. 

About the pointer, it seems CUDA 4.0 has a unified memory address space including not only multiple GPU memory, but also the main memory, won't that help? 

I am curious why people don't put useful functionality into the kernel, especially security things, I think the kernel the only thing we can trust...

Comment: We can trust the kernel because people put as little as possible into it :) Even if the server uses an encrypted disk, sending a single sector to the GPU for decryption is slower than doing it on CPU. It's hard to batch up enough operations for the GPU's parallelism to be useful. And even if you have unified address space, GPUs simply are not built for multiple pointer addressing stages. Once again, the typical operations in the kernel are not suited for taking advantage of the GPU's strengths, so they get the full effect of the GPU's weaknesses.

Answer (score 4):

Your impression that kernels don't parallelize is wrong. Modern kernels have adapted to multi-core/multi-thread CPUs quite well and deal with pretty much everything in a "parallel" way in that respect.

As for the GPUs, they are very different in terms of instructions they can process from CPUs. More adapted to vector floating point computations in particular. The Linux kernel essentially never uses that kind of operation. Exceptions whole be crypto and some raid code that can be well adapted to vector-type ops (and probably others, but still very limited).

So in general, the kernel itself doesn't actually need the kind of operations GPUs provide. For the times it needs them, you'll find modern CPU cores include specific instruction sets (like SSE, AES-NI, and such) or dedicated co-processors/offload engines (again for crypto and raid calcs, network packet checkums, etc...).

Comment: I think the modern CPUs do not have enough cores for OS's parallel processing. An OS kernel can handle multiple network queues with different cores, but the number of queues is limited by the #cores. This would limit the scalability and throughput. I notice that there is a project on GPU networking: PacketShader. It looks up IP-forwarding on GPUs and is very fast.  Another issue is that processing multiple requests is not all of the parallel processing. In parallel computations like OpenMP, it is more often to partition a single request and handle the small tasks on each core.

Answer (score 1):

> Modern GPUs can be used for more than just graphics processing; they can run general-purpose programs as well. While not well-suited to all types of programs, they excel on code that can make use of their high degree of parallelism. Most uses of so-called ``General Purpose GPU'' (GPGPU) computation have been outside the realm of systems software. However, recent work on software routers and encrypted network connections has given examples of how GPGPUs can be applied to tasks more traditionally within the realm of operating systems. These uses are only scratching the surface. Other examples of system-level tasks that can take advantage of GPUs include general cryptography, pattern matching, program analysis, and acceleration of basic commonly-used algorithms.

Cited from https://code.google.com/p/kgpu/

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I agree with Mat. The bottleneck of today's computation world is the operating system that is running on virtual threads. This is creating a demand in user space, for creating applications that use GPU. Yet the kernel still runs OS sequentially. For example, searching operating is integrated as OS feature, which checks the file system table sequentially, or by indexing and then searching using binary search algorithms. Both the operations are time consuming. Why not send the partial file system table to GPUs and fork the search operation. At processing level, most of the OS operations are nothing but arithmetic and logic computations and yet these operations waits for CPU. The problem concerning here is the latency involved for sending and receiving the operation/memory from CPU to GPU and back to CPU. Much research is necessary to decrease this latency. 
But the problem actually here is not the hardware latency (between CPU and GPU), but to estimate this latency by the OS. The OS must estimate the latency and decide whether processing in CPU is better or GPU is a better one. This is again hardware platform dependent. These problems could be addressed and researched. It just needs huge investment for research by OS companies.